# Why is my `favicon.ico` request not working?

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

I have a `favicon.ico` on my site.

In the HTML, I link to its location...

```
<link rel="icon" href="/assets/images/layout/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I also have this in my `.htaccess`.

```
# Redirect /favicon.ico requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^assets/images/layout/favicon\.ico [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^favicon\.(gif|ico|png|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/images/layout/favicon.ico [R=301,L]
```

...to redirect the `/favicon.ico` requests to a different location.

For some reason, every time I request [`favicon.ico`](http://toberua.com/favicon.ico) in my browser, I get `304 Not Modified` response with matching Etags and *apparently* a blank image, even though `/assets/images/layout/favicon.ico` *does* exist.

[image: Example]

I get the same issue when trying to access it wil the full path.

What is going on here? What is causing this `304`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would rather put this rule in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule ^favicon\.(gif|ico|png|jpe?g)$ /assets/images/layout/favicon.ico [L,NC]
```

Then if you have this in your web page:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

`/favicon.ico` will be **internally redirected** to `/assets/images/layout/favicon.ico`

I have tested this in IE, Firefox and Chrome and all 3 show this behavior that for the first time (or after clearing cache) I get `200` for favicon.ico but afterwards all browsers cache this icon file and don't bother to send another request to the server. With this setup I didn't find any `304` happening in my testing.

#### My access log:

**Chrome**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2011:23:58:15 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Geck
o) Chrome/11.0.696.60 Safari/534.24"
```

**IE**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2011:00:05:18 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .
NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

**Firefox**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2011:00:07:33 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the condition in case `favicon.ico` was requested in other directories besides root. As for not bothering to request it again, is there any way I can force it to? Even if I use Safari's *Reset Safari* option, I'm still getting the blank `favicon.ico`.

Comment: Do you mean forcing all browsers to fetch favicon.ico every time from server?

Comment: I ended up just placing the `favicon.ico` file in the root directory. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ _/img/ico/favicon.ico [L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon\.png$ _/img/ico/apple-touch-icon.png [L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon-precomposed\.png$ _/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png [L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed\.png$ _/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png [L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed\.png$ _/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png [L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed\.png$ _/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png [L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed\.png$ _/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png [L]
```

Comment: You can cover this in one line, perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37107216/4378314