# can't download own favicon

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, ftp, favicon

I have the favicon.ico at the root of my website
http://www.agrointel.ro/favicon.ico
However, when I try to access it, all I get is a 16x16 px blank file.
Remove the extension and it works fine (http://www.agrointel.ro/favicon displays the favicon.ico).
The same if I rename the file but keep the .ico
But I can't have both at once - name and extension.

Wouldn't be a big deal, except that feedburner doesn't see it neither, and it can only search "/favicon.ico" - finding nothing.

Comment: Have you tried a different favicon? Download one from somewhere and throw it on the server. It it works, you know it's your specific favicon.ico. Try creating one in a [different manner](http://www.favicon.cc/) and test that.

Comment: I did, no luck. It doesn't seem to be the file's fault, it works fine under every other name except "favicon.ico"

Comment: Anything funky in your [.htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906292/why-is-my-favicon-ico-request-not-working)?

Comment: I hope not:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to give this a read: [Apache and "favicon.ico".](http://robert.grefstad.com/linux/apache_favicon.html)

Mainly this:

> For some reason the execute bit has to be set on this file for Apache to use it. If you have shell access, type:
>
> `chmod +rx favicon.ico`

and this:

> Then edit  "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" and insert the following line:
>
> `AddType image/x-icon .ico`

Comment: This seems to be it but i don't have access to the httpd.conf. Can i put it in .htaccess instead?

Comment: Tried .htaccess and it doesn't work. I suspect the server has a dummy file to deliver, instead of a 404. It's just I can't override the dummy.

Comment: What are the permissions set to on favicon.ico?  It needs to have both read and write set.

Comment: Also, as a workaround you could try adding a rewrite entry in your .htaccess to redirect `favicon.ico` requests to `favicon` instead.  Something like this:
`RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ favicon`

Comment: I 777d the file, tried that rewrite and others and yet it's not working.

Comment: don't know if it's relevant, but the dummy file gets delivered for whatever extension i.e. favicon.*

Comment: This is quite strange.  The only explanation I can think of is that there is a RewriteRule set in `httpd.conf` that is causing all requests to `favicon.*` to be redirected to this "dummy" file.  Unfortunately it appears that you can't override that rule, perhaps because `AllowOverride none` is set.