# Modern favicons & htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Instead of having all the new favicon formats placed into the root directory of my website, I am placing them inside a subfolder.

To conform to the standards, as some browsers / device versions do not use the path as directed inside the html meta tags, but instead try to get the file from the website root anyway, I am creating a rewrite rule to redirect all these files to the actual location - but ONLY these files.

What I have come up with so far is the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/((apple\-touch\-icon|android\-chrome|favicon|mstile)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).png|manifest\.json|browserconfig\.xml|favicon\.ico|(apple\-touch\-icon\-precomposed|apple\-touch\-icon).png|safari-pinned-tab.svg)$ /favicon/$1 [L]
```

This should match all of the following files :

[image: favicons]

When testing the rule [at this site](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), the rule is not matched (see pic):

[image: rule not matched]

I would like to keep this rule on the same line, and due to the size standards changing, I wish to keep this dynamic (aka, instead of specifying each individual file, use a mask as I attempted to do).  I suspect something with my regex is off.

Please assist or provide a solution with the corrected regex pattern for what I am intending to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modern favicons + Rewrite

Following is a fairly robust pattern for mapping the modern favicon's using rewrite.

**Regex pattern, for reference**

> ^(browserconfig.xml|manifest.json|safari-pinned-tab.svg|(android-chrome|favicon|mstile)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+.png|apple-touch-icon(-precompressed.png|-[0-9]+x[0-9]+.png|.png)|manifest.json)$

**Usage: apply it to a rewrite rule (htaccess)**

This example assumes the rewrite destination where the favicon's are placed is a folder named `favicon` (or whatever folder you wish).

```
RewriteRule ^(browserconfig.xml|manifest.json|safari-pinned-tab.svg|(android-chrome|favicon|mstile)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+.png|apple-touch-icon(-precompressed.png|-[0-9]+x[0-9]+.png|.png)|manifest.json)$ /favicon/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This works for me on initial testing. I'm hosting two seperate websites on one server, with the secondary website occurring in a subdirectory. Favicon was the last thing giving me trouble, and this was the solution I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Additionally, another reason to keep maintaining an htaccess solution such as this is it covers the lowest baseline. It's possible some app or software out there could just grab the favicon (e.g. for quickly making some kind of shortcut or bookmark) and ignore your HTML.

Comment: Hi, I believe this actually redirects to a folder called `favicon`, not `favicons`

Comment: @Ben - The exact htaccess rule as pasted above does direct to /favicon,  however i also mention in brackets (or whatever folder you wish).  Good eye in spotting the mistake. I have corrected the text above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work.

- For one thing, its "precomposed" not "precompressed"
- It looks like you're evaluating 'manifest.json' twice
- Also, I don't know of any icons that show single-digit sizes; they
  would be really tiny, *e.g.*, apple-touch-icon-precomposed-1x1.  They
  are all 2 or 3 digits, *e.g.*,
  apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png or favicon-16x16.ico

Cheers!